# UIWindow addSubview handle events

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview, uiwindow, uicontrolstate

I want to build a **custom alert** by `UIViewController` and add its view as a subview to the current window. The view displays very well, but I can't handle any touch events.

I have tried many times to add a button to this viewcontroller and add a target. I have also tried adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and set view's `userInteractionEnabled` to `true`, but this also failed even when I cleared all subviews just left the button.

Have I missed something?

Here is the code:

## CustomAlert Viewcontroller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    backgroundView.alpha = 0.5;
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundView];


    backImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 300) / 2, (self.view.frame.size.height - 250) / 2, 300, 250)];

    backImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AlertBackground"];
    [self.view addSubview:backImage];

    confirmButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake( backImage.frame.origin.x + 100 , backImage.frame.origin.y + 250 - 40, 100, 26)];
    [self.view addSubview:confirmButton];
    [confirmButton addTarget:self action:@selector(confirmButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    confirmButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [confirmButton setTitle:@"click me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(void)confirmButtonClick:(UIButton*)sender{

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)show{
    UIWindow * window = (UIWindow*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    [window addSubview:self.view];
}
```

## Method call custom alert:

```
CustomAlert * alert = [[CustomAlert alloc]init];
[alert show];
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: Please show your code, so its easy to understand what you are doing.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks. i have put on there

Comment: @Abha  appreciate your help

Comment: @Castiel:  The problem is CustomAlert Viewcontroller isn't handled. 
You should `addChildViewController` before `addSubview`.

Comment: @anhtu i try to addchildviewcontroller for current window.rootviewcontroller before addsubview. but it gave me an error :  reason: 'child view controller:<CustomAlert: 0x14f8a9580> should have parent view controller:(null) but actual parent is:<REFrostedViewController: 0x14e579790>'

Comment: @anhtu did i misunderstanding?

Comment: @Castiel It means you added alert VC to a VC somewhere. With the code you showed, I didn't see where you added. Please check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rewrite your -show{} method with these

```
UIWindow * window = (UIWindow*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[window.rootViewController.view addSubview:self.view];
```

UPDATE:
And if previous don't help, try to overwrite

```
-(void)show{
    UIWindow * window = (UIWindow*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    [window.rootViewController addChildViewController:self];
    [window.rootViewController.view addSubview:self.view];
    [self didMoveToParentViewController:window.rootViewController];
}
```

Those three methods establish parent-child relations.

Comment: thx your help. I have tried this. it works well. And yesterday i changed my code to just use a uiview instead uiviewcontroller. it was good too.